# Meteor 1.3 and Angular 1

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

How to run Angular with Meteor 1.3 beta? New angular-meteor-1.3.7 release supports Meteor 1.3 but I can't find any information how to migrate to 1.3. After updating to 1.3 got error `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'angular'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make 1.3.7 work you need to `npm i --save angular angular-meteor` then in your main app file add:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-meteor';
```

I also had to double declare everything, ng-annotate seems to not be running with this update... I'll edit this answer if I figure that out. There are a few other bugs I've run into too regarding how my code is running (some stuff isn't showing, etc) after the update from 1.3.6 to 1.3.7.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: See other answer below to get 1.3.7 running.

I've been using angular-meteor 1.3.5 fine with Meteor 1.3 beta. The issue seems to be with angular-meteor 1.3.7 itself (i updated to test and got the same error), or maybe we're just not using it correctly, but I can't see any new docs for it yet.

My guess is you'll have to export the modules and import them into other files. Personally I'm using (and loving) modules on my serverside code, however I've left my frontend with the old style meteor build concat.

Simply put just use `meteor remove angular && meteor add angular@=1.3.5` and it **should** work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have downgraded angular to 1.3.6 and it's really works fine. This is will be my first step to migrate to meteor 1.3 But i guess  should be a way to run 1.3.7 with new meteor :)

Comment: I'm currently trying to figure it out myself. `npm i --save angular` fixes the angular module missing issue (with `import angular from 'angular';`) but it still says angular-meteor is missing, no matter how I try to import it.

They really should have made docs available either on the website or github before releasing this version with breaking changes..

Comment: 1.3.9 is also out right now claiming 1.3 support.  However, I haven't been able to successfully get it working even with their socially sample app.